# Prove that if $F_{X_n}\rightarrow F_X$ and $F_{Y_n}\rightarrow F_Y$ and $P(Y=1)=1$, then $F_{X_n,Y_n}\rightarrow F_{X,Y}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be sequences of random variables. Prove that if $F_{X_n}\rightarrow F_X$ and $F_{Y_n}\rightarrow F_Y$ and $P(Y=1)=1$, then $F_{X_n,Y_n}\rightarrow F_{X,Y}$.

---

As far as I know I have to prove that:

$P(\{X_n\le u\}\cap \{Y_n \le v\})\rightarrow P(\{X\le u\}\cap \{Y\le v\})$ pointwise. I don't know how can I use assumption that $P(Y=1)=1$. Any hint please?

Comment: A sequence of rv that converges in dist. to a constant, converges in probability to that constant.

Comment: Thank you, but how does this help me?

Comment: You wanna show $(X_n, 1) \to (X,1)$ in dist. and $|(X_n,Y_n) - (X_n, 1)| \to 0$ in probability. The second fact implies that $(X_n, Y_n)$ and $(X_n,1)$ converge in dist. to the same limit.

You can find a complete proof here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB3